# Solve for $x$: $\frac1e = e^{2x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I tried  making it to $e^{-1} = e^{2x}$

and had the exponents equal each other $-1=2x$

and the I solved for $x$, making it $x=-1/2$, but that answer is wrong.

please help

I don't know why that answer is wrong.

Comment: Why do you say the answer is wrong?

Comment: I had asked my professor about the question, and he said it was wrong, but didn't tell me why

Comment: Well, the answer is correct.

Comment: If the question really is reported correctly, and you are looking for the real solution, $x=-1/2$ is right.

Comment: I don't know haha, that's what I thought, thanks anyways

Comment: since the exponential function is injective your answer is correct.

Comment: @NilanC.Manoj it is only injective if you restrict its domain to the real axis... not if regarder as a function on the complex plane

Comment: SO, it is better to find the complex solutions also?

Answer (score 8):

Multiply both sides by $e$; then $e^{2x+1}=1$. The solutions to $e^z=1$ are given by $z=2\pi ni$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, thus the solutions for $x$ are given by
$$
x=\frac{2\pi ni -1}{2},\qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
If you only want real solutions, take $n=0$ to get $x=-1/2$ as you mentioned.

Answer (score -2):

$\frac1e = e^{2x}$ is in fact $e^{-1} = e^{2x}$  which applying lans is $lane^{-1} = lane^{2x}$ but this is simply ${-1} = {2x}$ which can only mean $x=-0.5$, so you are , in fact, correct.

Peace and Chicken grease.

Comment: By lan do you mean $\ln$?

Comment: that's correct..